# Aviation, what is the equivalent word for ships instead of aircraft?

Tags: nouns

From Dictionary.com:

> a·vi·a·tion noun
>
> 1. the design, development, production, operation, and use of aircraft, especially heavier-than-air aircraft.
> 2. military aircraft.

If *aviation* is the design, production, and use of aircraft, then what is the corresponding word for the design, production, and use of water vessels?

At first I thought it's *naval* or *navy*, but the first is an adjective and the latter describes the military branch itself, so those are probably not the right words.

Comment: Actually, *aviation* merely means the "flying & operation of aircraft", it does not cover design, development, production or other aspects.

Comment: @Kris - You don't know the (other) half of it. Most dictionaries (at least, the four I just checked, in addition to the one provided in the question) seem to disagree with you.

Comment: @JR Usage! cf. *navigation*, ask me for more details.

Comment: @Kris - Most Boeing employees work in the aviation industry, irrespective of whether they fly on the planes or operate the aircraft.

Comment: @J.R. So you need to update yourself on those differences. Patience!

Comment: GinKin: In some contexts, _marine_ or _maritime_ could work, particularly when _aviation_ functions as an adjective, as in _avaition regulations_ vs. _maritime regulations_, or _aviation technology_ vs. _marine technology_.

Comment: @JR I would suggest you Google your lines before posting the comments. See what happens and let us know.

Comment: @Kris - What makes you think I don't? [Marine technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_technology); [maritime regulations](http://www.labor.ky.gov/dows/oshp/oshr/Pages/Maritime-Regulations.aspx); [aviation regulations](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/); [aviation industry](https://www.osha.gov/OshDoc/data_General_Facts/factsheet-whistleblower-aviation-industry.pdf); [aviation safety](http://www.aviationsafetymagazine.com/); [aviation engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_engineering); [aviation manufacturing](http://www.gama.aero/about-us).

Comment: I propose navy-ation, or naviation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design, development and production of nautical vessels: **shipbuilding** or **boatbuilding** (depending on the type of craft);

The operation and use of nautical vessels: **navigation**:

> 1. The process or activity of accurately ascertaining one’s position and planning and following a route:
>      *Columbus corrected his westward course by celestial navigation*
> 2. The passage of ships:
>      *transporter bridges to span rivers without hindering navigation*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/navigation)

Comment: Hmm navigation isn't exclusive for ships like aviation is for planes.

Comment: No, it's not; but that doesn't mean it's not the word to use.

Comment: @GinKin It was exclusive until the flyers hijacked it.

Comment: @Kris you can also navigate on foot or when driving a car.

Comment: @GinKin I can "navigate" sitting beside the driver, or sitting at home. Think of it. -- That "navigation" is a different kind of animal, do not confuse with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider **[seamanship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seamanship)** which covers maritime navigation as well. Still does not cover ship building though.

> It involves topics and development of specialised skills including: **navigation** and international maritime law; weather, meteorology and forecasting; watchstanding; **ship-handling** and small boat handling; operation of deck equipment, anchors and cables; ropework and line handling; communications; **sailing**; engines; execution of evolutions such as towing; cargo handling equipment, dangerous cargoes and cargo storage; dealing with emergencies; survival at sea and search and rescue; and fire fighting.

Marine, maritime, naval, nautical are used before nouns depending on the context also.

Note: There is the word airmanship similar to seamanship.

Comment: If you design planes, you can say you work in aviation, but if you design boats or ships, you wouldn't say you work in seamanship.  Also, *seamanship*  covers skills like navigation and the use of navigational systems, but not shipbuilding. It's "The art or skill of handling, working, and navigating a ship" [m-m](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seamanship)

Comment: @DjinTonic Thank you for the details. I've already mentioned that _seamanship_ does not cover ship building. However, there isn't a term that covers everything the OP is asking for: "the design, production, and use of water vessels". _Shipbuilding_ is a separate field. I've tried to find the closest and most comprehensive hypernym for the maritime equivalent; and offered an alternative approach also.

Answer (score 1):

**Seafaring** is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seafaring) as "the use of the sea for travel or transportation". That covers most aspects of using a boat on the water, and it's often used to refer to the technology and knowhow needed to go by sea, including both boatbuilding and navigation, e.g. "Its power and wealth came from seafaring and trade, and its cultural and economic influence stretched from its home island of Crete all the way to Egypt."